# Calculate the Average of Numbers from command output

Tags: bash, shell, nvidia

Need help with a nvidia-smi command. When i run the following command:

`nvidia-smi --format=csv --query-gpu=utilization.gpu`

It returns:

```
utilization.gpu [%]
89 % 
45 %
22 %
68 %
```

I want to have a script that uses these returned values and calculate an average number.
So it should do this 89 + 45 + 22 + 68 = 224 / 4 = 56

Is there a way of doing this ?

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nvidia-smi --format=csv --query-gpu=utilization.gpu | awk '/[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]%/ { tot+=$1;cnt++ } END { print tot/cnt }'
```

Pipe the output of nvidia-smi ... to awk. Process lines that have a one or more digits, a space and then a "%". Create a running total (tot) and also, count the number of occurrences (cnt) At the end, divide tot by cnt and print the result.

Comment: An alternative implementation: `| awk 'NR>1{ tot+=$1 } END{ print tot/(NR-1) }'`

Comment: @Cyrus not much correct but works: `bash -c 'IFS=+;echo $((($*)/$#))' _ $(nvidia-smi --format=csv,noheader,nounits --query-gpu=utilization.gpu)`

Answer (score 1):

```
nvidia-smi --format=csv --query-gpu=utilization.gpu | tail -n +2 | awk '{ sum+=$1 }END { print sum/NR }'
```

Use tail to get all but not the first line, then compute the mean of column 1.

Comment: No need for `tail -n +2` Just do: `nvidia-smi --format=csv,noheader,nounits --query-gpu=utilization.gpu | awk '{s+=$1}END{print s/NR}'`